# inserting (ajax called) php function at a certain point

Tags: php, ajax

I have a loading function that is called when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. An ajax call is made that calls an "external" php file (`ajax.php`)

Looks like this:

```
// Post data to ajax.php
            $.post('ajax.php', {

                action        : 'scrollpagination',
                number        : $settings.nop,
                offset        : offset,
```

`ajax.php` is a php file that queries a database and **echoes** the results.

Now my problem is that I somehow can't seem to figure out how to make `ajax.php` echo these results in a certain `location` (in the html of my index.php).

In my case, this location is a `div` container in my `index.php` file.

So, I would like to echo the results coming from `ajax.php` within these `div` tags in my `index.php`:

```
<div id="container123">
//results of ajax.php
</div>
```

I hope this is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You would update the dom in the callback function of `$.post`

```
          $.post('ajax.php', {

            action        : 'scrollpagination',
            number        : $settings.nop,
            offset        : offset}
           ,function(response){
                $('#container123').html(response);
           });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to put the results of an ajax request in a div.

```
$('#container123').load('ajax.php', {
        action        : 'scrollpagination',
        number        : $settings.nop,
        offset        : offset
});
```

Comment: I forgot about `.load` this is a better way